# How do I convert a sum to an algebraic expression?

Tags: calculus, induction

Something something Riemann sum to integral is the most that I remember. I just don't remember how we did it or whether or not that would be the best method for doing it.

Let $ \theta(n) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k $

and $ \phi(n) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} 2k-1 $

Let $ P(n) $ be the statement $ n^3 = \psi(n)$, where
 $ \psi(n) = \phi(\theta(n)) - \phi(\theta(n-1)) $.

I need to prove that $ P(n) $ is true for all positive $ n $ by induction. My only progress was defining the series provided in terms of the functions that I created, $ \theta(n) $ and $ \phi(n) $. To complete the proof, I need those two functions in algebraic form. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: You need to put dollar signs $ around your maths text.

Comment: Sorry. Used notation for the TeXtheWorld extension; it filled it in correctly for me and I didn't notice the mistake.

Comment: Do you know the simplified forms for both of your series? If you don't, try deriving them, using the fact that you can sum each series from below _or_ from above..

Comment: My entire problem is deriving them. Is there some way to derive them trivially (relatively, as in there's a method)?

Comment: Yes there is.. Use the hint that I gave above. Alternatively, have a look on this site, there have been plenty of answers done previously. Or do you want me to post an answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's a bit too vague for me; I'm not that clever.

Comment: I'll make a post now for the first one.. Then you can do the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} k &= 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n \\
&= n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + \cdots + 1 \\
\end{align}

where in the second line we just reversed the order in which we summed. Now if we add the two lines, notice that term by term we get $n + 1$, i.e

\begin{align}
(n) + 1 &= n + 1 \\
(n - 1) + 2 &= n + 1 \\
(n - 2) + 3 &= n + 1 \\
\vdots
\end{align}

and hence we find

\begin{align}
2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} k &= \underbrace{(n + 1) + (n + 1) + \cdots + (n + 1)}_{\text{n times}} \\
&= n(n + 1) \\\\
\implies \sum_{k=1}^{n} k &= \frac{1}{2} n(n + 1)
\end{align}

Now try it for the other series, you should get

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (2k - 1) = n^{2}$$

Comment: $ 1 + 3 + 5 + ... + (2n-1) \\ (2n-1) + (2n-3) + (2n-5) + ... + 1 \\ 2n^2 = 2\phi(n) \\ \phi(n) = n^2 $

Comment: What does this method not work for?

Comment: Could you show me an example series that would require some other method?

Comment: One last question. So the method is basically just writing one from $1$ to $n$ and the other from $n$ to $1$ and adding them, looking for a pattern, then dividing by $2$?